# Error en exportar modulo con node js

Tags: nodejs, express

necesito exportar la la variable io, pero a la hora de exportar  tengo el siguiente error:
La primer imagen muestra donde esta la variable a exportar (appjs)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
en la siguiente imagen muestro como lo exporto
[image: archivo app.js]

y en esta imagen muestro como importo la variable en el archivo usuario.js
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el error es el siguiente ayúdenme por favor soy nuevo en socket io
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

bueno la impresion de usuarios, salas y usuario conectado no tiene nada que ver con el erro. gracias de antemano

Comment: El código va como texto y no como imagen

Comment: Hola, te invito a leer [ask]. Recuerda que es preferible siempre copiar el código en vez de  subir imágenes del mismo. Puedes leer [mcve] para que te des una idea de cómo crear una buena pregunta. Saludos